# javascript: issue with a prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype, this, loopbackjs

I am using this code in the context of `loopbackjs`.
I want to overwrite the `toJSON` method in order to return different data depending of if the caller is the owner of an object.

```
Model.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  var current = loopback.getCurrentContext();
  var obj = getAllData(this);
  if (!current) {
    logger.error("Can't get current context in prototype.toJSON. Ignoring and returning 'safe' info");
    return getSafeData(obj);
  }   
  var token = current.get("accessToken");
  if (!token) {
    logger.debug("Current context has no token, may be anonymous");
    return getSafeData(obj);
  }   
  this.owner(function(err, owner) {
    if (err) {
      logger.error(err);
      return getSafeData(obj);
    }

    if (token.userId == owner.id) {
      logger.debug(obj); //here the log shows the correct object
      return obj;
    } else {
      return getSafeData(obj);
    }
  }); 
}   

var getAllData = function(obj) {
  var json = {}; 
  for (var p in obj.__data) {
    json[p] = obj.__data[p];
  }   
  return json;
}   

var getSafeData = function(obj) {
  var json = {}; 
  for (var p in obj) {
     if (Model.settings.protected.indexOf(p)  >= 0) continue;
     json[p] = obj[p];
  }
  return json;
}
```

The problem I have is that when the token is not present (anonoymous call), the code doesn't enter the async `owner` function, and `getSafeData(obj)` is called, returning the complete object in the frontend.

But whenever the `this.owner`async method is called, in the front-end I get "No content". But the logger debug output after the owner check, before returning, shows the complete object.

I have no idea why. Any idea? Could the async call on `this`be the problem?

Comment: Where is the code for writing "No content"?

Comment: yes, exactly, the result of calling `this.owner` function is whatever `this.owner` function returns = not what the async function called within this.owner returns

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't get it. Won't the return statement inside `this.owner()`, e.g. `return obj`, also be the return from the `Model.prototye.toJSON` function? How do I make `Model.prototype.toJSON`return the value of the `this.owner` call?

Comment: Oh....did the prototype function already terminate by the time `this.owner`returns? Do I thus need some callback function in order to catch that value?

Comment: what does `this.owner` function return - not the callback

Comment: I don't know but probably nothing....

Comment: It strucks me that it is NOT POSSIBLE!!!!??? I can't hold off the prototype functoin to return until the async function is returning....there is no callback  provided to the toJSON function, and I can't change that because it's framework code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it strucks me that it can't be done, because I should not change the toJSON interface to accept a callback, it's probably used all over the framework.

BUT - in this case, I don't actually need to query asynchronously for the owner object. What I actually just need is the ID of the owner.

Thus by just doing

```
if (token.userId == this.ownerId) {
```

instead of

```
this.owner(...);
```

I get what I need.